# Is TinyMCE editor compatible with rails 2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce

Is **TinyMCE editor** compatible with rails 2? what are better editors apart from **fck editor** that can be used in rails, is it compatible with rails 2 as well?

**EDIT:**
Is TinyMCE editor customizable? html tags can be used in the editor space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, TinyMCE is compatible with all versions of Rails, because it really has nothing to do with it, all frontend (client-side) editors are just "decorators" for textareas, meaning Rails doesn't care what's in them.

I normally avoid using editors like TinyMCE or FCK, because they force me to "reverse" my development workflow - they come with everything and I need to strip 90% of functionality down. So a better approach would be to use something like markdown and educate users on it's use.

And yes, pretty much all editors are heavily customizable - I recommend you read their respective manuals